# Fatal error when try add snippets code on functions.php Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, filter

I'm trying to make a filter in `functions.php` of my website in Wordpress, to show some information on the customer's invoice:

```
echo get_post_meta($order_id,'bairro',true) . get_post_meta($order_id,'billing_complemento',true);
```

I've tried the following, it's retrieving the information all together, I wanted to divide it into lines. I tried it this way:

```
    <tr class=“bairro”>
            <td><b>Bairro: </b> R$ <?php echo get_post_meta($order_id,'bairro',true) ?></td>
        </tr>
 <tr class=“billing_complemento”>
            <td><b>Complemento: </b> <?php echo get_post_meta($order_id,'billing_complemento',true) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
```

but it’s giving a fatal error on the site, I believe it’s just some kind of closure. Someone to save me there?

Comment: what is the problem now? you can store meta data into a variable and then you can divide in line.

Comment: What is the fatal error it returns?

Comment: The problem is that the `get_post_metadata` function doesn't allow you to access the current value. This means you aren't able to transform the value, just replace it. Also you need to use `add_filters()`